# Faster Sqlite insert from another table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have an Sqlite DB which I am doing updates on and its very slow. I am wondering if I am doing it the best way or is there a faster way. My tables are:

```
create table files( 
    fileid integer PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT not null,
    sha256 TEXT,
    created INT,
    mtime INT,
    inode INT,
    nlink INT,
    fsno INT,
    sha_id INT,
    size INT not null
);

create table fls2 (
    fileid integer PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT not null UNIQUE, 
    size INT not null, 
    sha256 TEXT not null, 
    fs2, 
    fs3, 
    fs4, 
    fs7
);
```

Table 'files' is actually in an attached DB named ttb. I am then doing this:

```
UPDATE fls2 
SET fs3 = (
SELECT inode || 'X' || mtime || 'X' || nlink 
FROM 
   ttb.files
WHERE 
   ttb.files.fsno = 3 
AND 
   fls2.name = ttb.files.name 
AND
   fls2.sha256 = ttb.files.sha256
);
```

So the idea is, fls2 has values in 'name' which are also present in ttb.files.name. In ttb.files there are other parameters which I want to insert into the corresponding rows in fls2. The query works but I assume the matching up of the two tables is taking the time, and I wonder if theres a more efficient way to do it. There are indexes on each column in fls2 but none on files. I am doing it as a transaction, and pragma journal = memory (although sqlite seems to be ignoring that because a journal file is being created).

It seems slow, so far about 90 minutes for around a million rows in each table.

One CPU is pegged so I assume its not disk bound.

Can anyone suggest a better way to structure the query?

EDIT: EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN

```
|--SCAN TABLE fls2
`--CORRELATED SCALAR SUBQUERY 1
   `--SCAN TABLE files
```

Not sure what that means though. It carries out the SCAN TABLE files for each SCAN TABLE fls2 hit?

EDIT2:
Well blimey, Crtl-C the query which had been running 2.5 hours at that point, exit Sqlite, run sqlite with the files DB, create index (sha256, name) - 1 minute or so. Exit that, run Sqlite with the main DB. Explain shows that now the latter scan is done with the index. Run the update - takes 150 seconds. Compared to >150 minutes, thats a heck of a speed up. Thanks for the assistance.

TIA, Pete

Comment: If you want performance over a large dataset, you might want to consider switching to a more robust database than SQLite.

Comment: Thats my worry. This is a one shot job though, for sorting out a large filesystem. I don't know how much faster mysql, for instance, would be. At least it would use 4 cores I assume, so the CPU bound stuff would be 4 times faster.

Comment: What indexes do you have for the files table? What's the `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN` output for that insert?

Comment: Ah, now I see where you said there are no indexes on files. There's your problem - it's looking at all one million rows in files for each row of fls2. No wonder it's slow.

Comment: Tried explain query plan on an (empty) knocked up dummy of the DB, hope it behaves in the same way as with the filled DB. Plan edited into the question.

Comment: Might help, but be careful, because it's unsafer. Start the connection with `PRAGMA synchronous=OFF; PRAGMA journal_mode=OFF;`

Answer (score 0):

> There are indexes on each column in fls2

Indexes are used for faster selection. They slow down inserts and updates. Maybe removing the one for fls2.fs3 helps?

Comment: I know what you mean but in this case I think the searching before the updating is the problem. I was previously able to insert a million or so rows into fls2 in around 20 seconds, but that was pure insert into from another table, no matching of the two tables.

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert on sqlite, but on some databases it is more performant to insert the data into temporary table, delete them, then insert them from the temp table.

```
Insert into tmptab
Select fileid,
    name,
    size,
    sha256,
    fs2, 
    inode || 'X' || mtime || 'X' || nlink,
    fs4, 
    fs7
From fls2
Inner join files on 
   fls2.name = ttb.files.name 
AND
   fls2.sha256 = ttb.files.sha256

delete from
Fls2 where exists (select 1 from tmptab where tmptab.<primary key> = fls2.<primary key>)

Insert into fls2  select * from tmptab
```

Comment: Have a feeling if I really knew what I was doing this would be the way to go, I have 3 updates to do on fls2 from 3 attached DBs that could probably be done at the same time. 15 years ago maybe but now its just too dim in my memory! I'll take a good look at your code though, maybe I'll be able to remember with this help. OTOH maybe the indexing will get enough performance to get the job done in the less elegant way!